# How to open existing android project(build.gradle) into android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am new to `Android Studio`.I have an existing android project which was build from android studio. now I need to `open` that  project from build.grade(that project's file)file.I followed this step 
**File-->Open-->build.gradle(from that existing project)**
But it shows the processing window as below image for so Long time doesn't responding well.

So any one have idea about this please help me.

[image]

Comment: What if you try building it from command line? Open cmd in the project directory and execute `gradlew.bat assemble`.

Comment: Actually i had a project already just want to import it for that proceed with by the following File-->Open-->build.gradle(from that existing project).

Comment: usually i follow this step to import my project to android studio it will go but for the last 2 days the loading process takes so long time.

Comment: i had tried with going to offline work and in complier uncheck the use in process build but no use

Comment: If you build the project from command line you have a better idea of which task hangs.

Comment: thanks bro let me try it and know for u.

Comment: rciovati while  building in command prompt also it remains the same here what I got from command line build 
`error listing versions of com.android.support:support-v4 using class org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.MavenVersionLister$1. will attempt an alternate way to list versions. This behaviour has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in gradle 2.0.
> Configuring >5/6 projects > Resolving dependencies ':test-app:_debugCompile'`

Comment: Post the build.gradle

Answer (score 1):

First, we need your build.gradle

Second, i can make a guess from what you have posted till now.

- Check your build.gradle for unused or missing projects in your project directory by checking dependencies area

as i can understand from "**error listing versions of com.android.support:support-v4 using class org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.MavenVersionLister$1. will attempt an alternate way to list versions. This behaviour has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in gradle 2.0**" 
this.It may be related to repositories.

Check whether you have this or not in dependencies area. If something else is written there, remove it and add the correct one that i wrote below.

```
dependencies {
    ...
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
    }
...
}
```

- and my another guess is, there is something wrong in your support-v4 library implementation

check whether you have

```
    dependencies {
...
        compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0'
...
    }
```

this or not. If not , add the line starts with compile that i wrote above.
And
If you have something like,

`compile project(':support-v4'`)

remove that line.