# How to open another project in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am new to Android Studio. I have two Android projects. I can open individual projects without error and both are working correctly.

For the current issue, I checked other links as ([How to open existing android project(build.gradle) into android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25645910/how-to-open-existing-android-projectbuild-gradle-into-android-studio) ), but no help to me.

[image]

The problem is that when I try to open another project via "Open" or "Reopen Project," nothing asks and simply close the first one and re-open the new one.

I tried 2–3 times, but the same thing happened. My question is how to open two projects simultaneously so I can compare the files to understand the project(s).

**Updated 1** :- I do not see option "Appearance & Behavior" in My Android Studio. Something I missing?
[image]

**Update 2 on 31 dec** :- When I click on "Check for update", a popup comes as below image of version **Stable Channel 1.5.1** (I checked with "Help" -> "About" too and Automatic update too) and when I click download option, it goes to [Canary version](http://tools.android.com/download/studio/canary/latest/) and suggest to download zip.

**I do not understand which version I download**. Is there any setting which update automatically ( I tick automatic stable version option as below image, but not automatically update) rather than manual activity of zip download?

[image: check update for latest version and automatic update setting]

[image]

Comment: when you choose to re open it asks whether you want to open it in another window or same. Select another/new window from that option

Comment: Accept the answer if it helped so this question will be no longer be open

Comment: I update the question , please check this

Comment: dont worry just unzip it and use it after that you wont face any problem with the update as it will automatically update itself

Comment: Ok, but my question is which version I download? canary or stable ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its too long time to give answer but above any answer is not work for me.

The reason is I did not get this option in my `Android Studio` and also its not download the latest things (May be that I have very old version which does not support the current latest version).

So for the solution, I have only option was I download the whole latest Android Studio and then check this option and I got this as per above answer I also enable to open 2 separate project.

Answer (score 9):

You Must have by mistake clicked on remember my choice when opening new project.
so open settings in android studio and do as shown in below image.[image]

Comment: how does this answer differ from the former two? beside a screenshot.

Comment: i think screenshot gives a better understanding

Comment: for navigating to a radio button?!

Comment: thanks, but I do not have this option, check updated question

Answer (score 5):

In Android Studio:

`File` > `Settings...` > `Appearance & Behavior` > `System Settings` >

`Project Opening`

Select `Confirm window to open project in`

Comment: thanks, but I do not have this option, check updated question

Comment: which version are you running? tried to update to the most recent?

Comment: current version is 1.0.1 and when click 'Check Update', popup comes with 'New version available - 1.5.1'. can I update it and will solve my issue?

Comment: do the update anyway, the missing options will also be there.

Answer (score 4):

In the menu, go to

> File -> Settings -> Appearance and Behavior -> System Settings

.

And under 'Project opening' remove the selection of "Open project in the same window" by selecting one of the other options.

Comment: thanks, but I do not have this option, check updated question

Comment: What version of Android Studio are you using? Try searching for "Open project in the same window" directly.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if these changes are in recent Android Studio or specific to Mac build but I see the following path -

> Android Studio -> preferences -> Apperances & Behavior -> System Setting

Shortcut - <kbd>⌘ command</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd>

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Android Studio Electric Eel | 2022.1.1 Beta 5**

> Android Studio -> Settings -> Apperances & Behavior -> System Settings
> -> Projects ->  Reopen projects on startup - > **Select checkbox ask**